# How to write template for properties file with multiple group or section

Tags: shell, templates, properties

I am new to shell script and trying to create a template for properties file with multiple groups. I found many links for creating simple properties file but is their any way to create groups in properties file using template.

Properties file should look something like this:

```
[dev]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:h2:mem:mem_test;MODE=Oracle
JDBC_USERNAME =
JDBC_PASSWORD =

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://localhost:8080/Central/api/AppService

[qa]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@qa-oracle:1521:qa
JDBC_USERNAME = qauser
JDBC_PASSWORD = qapass

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://qa-services/Central/api/AppService

[prod]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@prod-oracle:1521:prod
JDBC_USERNAME = scott
JDBC_PASSWORD = tiger

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://prod-services/Central/api/AppService
```

Comment: Please tell more about your requirements. Do you want somethng like `for group in dev qa prod; do echo "[${group}]"; for key in ...` to generate your example without values ?

Comment: Can you explain what it will do, as i am new to bash scripting. for group in dev qa prod; do echo "[${group}]"; for key in ...

Comment: @WalterA the template should be in a way that above properties file format should be generated after executing the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of the next code to a file (append `> template.txt` afer the last `done`).

```
for group in dev qa prod; do
   echo "[${group}]"
   for key in JDBC_URL JDBC_USERNAME JDBC_PASSWORD SERVICE_ENDPOINT; do
      echo "${key} ="
   done
   # additional blank line
   echo
done
```